# Анимация движения с помощью безье C#

Tags: c#, winforms, анимация, кривые-безье

Мне необходимо анимировать движение чего-либо, для примера, `Control'а`, точнее его `x` координаты, так, чтобы `x` координата зависела от кривой безье `EaseInOutQuint(x1=0.83, y1=0, x2=0.17, y2=1)`. (Прямо как в *css*!) Но я не могу придумать как это правильно сделать. Для того, чтобы понять как у меня вообще движется `Control`, я нарисовал два графика. Первый график - сама кривая. Сначала движение идёт медленно, потом проходит очень быстро, и опять идёт медленно.

[image: какой график движения должен быть]

И как получается на самом деле:

[image: как есть]

Получаю точки для графика так:

```cs
void GetBezierPoints()
{
   Dictionary<double, double> points = new Dictionary<double, double>() { };
   for (double i = 0; i < 1.04; i += 0.001)
   {
        i = Math.Round(i, 3);
        points.Add(GetCubicBezier(i, 0.83, 0.17), GetCubicBezier(i, 0, 1));
   }
}
double GetCubicBezier(double t, double p1, double p2)
{
    double[] p = new double[4] { 0, p1, p2, 1 };
    double result =
        Math.Pow(1 - t, 3) * p[0] +
        3 * t * Math.Pow(1 - t, 2) * p[1] +
        3 * Math.Pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) * p[2] +
        Math.Pow(t, 3) * p[3];
    return result;
}
```

И по идее здесь(где я не могу понять как) я получаю прогресс и двигаю Control в определённую позицию.

```cs
void MoveControl()
{
    double fraction = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds / animationDuration;
    double progress = GetCubicBezier(fraction, 0, 1); // что здесь должно быть я без понятия
    int nextControlPos = progress * endPos;
    control.Location.X = nextControlPos;
}
```

Вообще не понимаю как сделать правильно(или сильно туплю и не вижу очевидного :c )

Я использовал **решение 3**, как наиболее подходящее вопросу.

Comment: В анимации где-то должен быть цикл.

Comment: @aepot цикл - System.Timers.Timer с интервалом 1000/60, который вызывает метод MoveControl. Проблема в том, чтобы определить куда двигать в соответствии с кривой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Движок анимации

Для того, чтобы воспользоваться любой формулой нелинейной анимации, я написал класс, анимирующий свойство типа `Point` для любого объекта содержащего такое свойство.

```cs
public class PointAnimation
{
    private readonly int _fps;
    private readonly Func<double, double> _curve;

    public PointAnimation() : this(60) { }

    public PointAnimation(Func<double, double> curve) : this(curve, 60) { }

    public PointAnimation(int fps) : this(x => x, fps) { }

    public PointAnimation(Func<double, double> curve, int fps)
        => (_curve, _fps) = (curve, fps);

    public async Task AnimateAsync<T>(T instance, Expression<Func<T, Point>> exp, Point end, double duration) where T : class
    {
        string propertyName = ((MemberExpression)exp.Body).Member.Name;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        Point start = (Point)propertyInfo.GetValue(instance);
        Point distance = new Point(end.X - start.X, end.Y - start.Y);

        double delay = 1000 / _fps;
        double step = delay / duration;
        int intDelay = (int)delay;
        int ms = 0;

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (double progress = 0; progress <= 1; progress += step)
        {
            ms += intDelay;
            int adjDelay = ms - (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            if (adjDelay <= 0) 
                continue; // слишком много прошло времени, кадр опоздал, пропускаем
            double curveProgress = _curve(progress);
            double x = start.X + distance.X * curveProgress;
            double y = start.Y + distance.Y * curveProgress;
            propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, new Point((int)Math.Round(x), (int)Math.Round(y)));
            await Task.Delay(adjDelay);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, end);
    }
}
```

Никаких таймеров, всё по-взрослому, только [асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). Здесь весь код, я ничего не спрятал.

Конструктор `PointAnimation` принимает аргументы

1. Количество кадров в секунду
2. Функция анимации
3. Либо и то и другое сразу

Метод `AnimateAsync` принимает аргументы:

1. Класс любого типа
2. Свойство типа `Point`, которое содержит класс, в виде лямбда-выражения, начальная точка будет взята именно из него
3. Конечная точка
4. Продолжительность анимации в миллисекундах

С этим классом анимации вы можете использовать любую функцию, только стоит помнить, что входной аргумент изменяется от `0` до `1` и выходной также должен изменяться от `0` до `1`.

#### Формула кривой

Полная формула Безье хорошо подходит для построения графика, но она, как мне кажется, избыточна для проекции кривой Безье на время `t`. То есть для простого искажения значения времени, чтобы получить нелинейную анимацию.

Математики [предлагают](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121755) следующее: f<sub>a</sub>(x) = x<sup>a</sup> / (x<sup>a</sup> + (1 - x)<sup>a</sup>)

Что можно описать в виде простого метода

```cs
private double EaseInOutBlend(double t, double power)
{
    double p = Math.Pow(t, power);
    double np = Math.Pow(1 - t, power);
    return p / (p + np);
}
```

Где `t` меняется от `0` до `1`.
И здесь можно управлять кривой с помощью степени, в которую возводится `x`, кстати, эта степень - не обязательно целое число, можете например возвести в `1.5`.

А пользоваться этим всем достаточно легко. Например, пусть будет у вас на форме `Label` и `Button` с именами по умолчанию `label1` и `button1` соответственно.
Тогда можно написать вот такой обработчик клика кнопки.

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    PointAnimation animation = new PointAnimation(p => EaseInOutBlend(p, 2));
    Point end = new Point(label1.Location.X + 200, label1.Location.Y + 200);
    await animation.AnimateAsync(label1, c => c.Location, end, 1000);
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

#### Тригонометрия

Бонусом можете еще такую функцию попробовать

```cs
private double CosBlend(double t)
{
    return (1 - Math.Cos(Math.PI * t)) / 2;
}
```

#### Кривая Безье

А вот и кривая Безье на основе аппроксимации X при поиске Y.

```cs
public class CubicBezier
{
    private const double _precision = 0.0001;
    private readonly double _x1, _x2, _y1, _y2;

    public CubicBezier(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        _x1 = x1;
        _y1 = y1;
        _x2 = x2;
        _y2 = y2;
    }

    private double Evaluate(double a, double b, double m)
    {
        return 3 * a * (1 - m) * (1 - m) * m 
            + 3 * b * (1 - m) * m * m 
            + m * m * m;
    }

    public double Transform(double t)
    {
        double start = 0.0;
        double end = 1.0;
        while (true)
        {
            double midpoint = (start + end) / 2;
            double estimate = Evaluate(_x1, _x2, midpoint);
            if (Math.Abs(t - estimate) < _precision)
                return Evaluate(_y1, _y2, midpoint);
            if (estimate < t)
                start = midpoint;
            else
                end = midpoint;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    CubicBezier bezier = new CubicBezier(0.83, 0.0, 0.17, 1.0);
    PointAnimation animation = new PointAnimation(p => bezier.Transform(p));
    Point end = new Point(label1.Location.X + 200, label1.Location.Y + 200);
    await animation.AnimateAsync(label1, c => c.Location, end, 500);
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: А можно ли это всё-таки сделать, не избегая безье? Или слишком муторно получится

Comment: @Cordis муторно, с ходу я не нашел формулу рисования кривой по 4 точкам, точнее она есть, та что у вас в вопросе очень на похожа на то что надо. Но я не нашел как переложить ее на формулу отношения `tcurve = f(t)`. И примеров нигде нет. Понятно было только что в качетсве исходных данных должны идти 4 точки и `t`, а на выходе модифицированный `t`. Я полинтернета перерыл на самом деле, включая англоязычный и более вменяемого, чем в ответе способа сделать `ease-in-out`, я не нашел.

Comment: @Cordis второй момент, то что вам надо реализовывать здесь, например есть уже готовое реализованное в WPF - `DoubleAnimation` и куча анимаций для других типов свойств, готовое, из коробки. Так что если вам надо, чтобы в интерфейсе красиво ползало и скакало, переливаясь цветами и плавно исчезало, изучайте WPF.

Comment: @Cordis в любом случае, движок написан, можно издеваться над формулами сколько душе угодно.

Comment: Передо мной стояла задача именно реализовать движение в зависимости от функции. Control был тут лишь для примера. До асинхронности я уже дошёл, но вот анимации на ней делать не додумался. Походу пойду к своему преподу по математике и буду выпрашивать у него помощь) Спасибо!

Comment: @Cordis проверьте, добавил в ответ Безье. Очевидно, `X` координата здесь не влияет на проекцию.

Comment: я нашёл реализацию через безье на github. Скоро дополню ответ

Comment: @Cordis так я уже дополнил. Внизу ответа. Забирайте и пользуйтесь. :)

Comment: Так ведь эта реализация и была у меня. И именно она дала второй график, который работает не правильно. Я нашёл код, который используя время возвращает прогресс в таком виде, как на первом графике. По моим исследованиям, если не учитывать X при расчёте, он будет 0.5

Comment: @Cordis ваша ошибка была в том, что вы брали проекцию на ось `X`, а надо было на ось `Y`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122588/discussion-between-cordis-and-aepot).

Comment: await Task.Delay((int)delay) не учитывает длительность вычислений. Stopwatch показывает время выполнения >1500мс, вместо заданных 1000мс. обидно, однако:(

Comment: @Cordis исправлено в ответе.

Comment: А можно в виде nuget-пакета с лицензией MIT или Apache!?

Comment: @Blackmeser чем вас сделай-сам пакет с лицензией Creative Commons не устраивает?