# c# Некорректно отображается форма

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, metro-framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел сделать плавное отображение формы с помощью кода:

```
    public Shift()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Opacity = 0;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if ((Opacity += 0.05d) == 1) timer.Stop();
        });
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Start();

        Activate();
    }
```

Но по итогу получается так.
Использую MetroFramework.Forms

Comment: В Winforms не поддерживается полупрозрачность, совсем. Пора бы начать изучать WPF.

Comment: Хотя для самой формы вроде можно за счет поддержки операционной системой https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Спасибо. Уже нашёл, с чем это может быть связано. Так же, при запуске формы добавил небольшую "анимацию" увеличения формы из 0 в нужное значение. Выглядит красиво)

Comment: В любом случае в формах красиво - это через боль и страдания. Я в свое время плюнул и ушел в WPF, там оно из коробки всё есть без проблем. Сложнее всего освоить XAML, но если вы верстали на HTML, то процесс немного похож. В общем, оно того стоит.

Comment: И анимации там родные на любой вкус безо всяких самопальных таймеров. [Вот такие мучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265190/373567) в WPF отсутствуют в принципе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, решение - изменить ShadowType на None (либо любой другой)