# Изменение значения числа одинарной точности в зависимости от времени

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как при помощи времени в юнити, плавно изменять значение в диапазоне от `0.0f` до `1.0f` включительно?

Промежуток времени 1.5с.

Comment: Не понятно, тип переменой какой?)))

Comment: думаю кроме как переменной float особо больше не размахнешься

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле хороший и я против его закрытия.

Comment: Это возможно при помощи библиотеки LeanTween или любого аналога коих существует достаточно. Но вопрос желательно переформулировать до более конкретного.

Comment: @Andrew насколько плавно, изменений в секунду сколько? нужно ли применять кривые при анимации значения, либо линейно? без понятия, что хочет автор. Но самопальное решение [уже есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265190/373567), так что это своего рода еще и дубликат.

Comment: @aepot вне зависимости от всех вариаций этого вопроса это решается через LeanTween. И не имеет смысла использовать самопальное решение т.к. линтвин маленький и легковесный сам по себе. А это самопальное решение написано под винформс и его еще и адаптировать нужно под юнити. Я все еще за переоткрытие. Этот вопрос полезен для создания анимированных меню, например.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте больше деталей.

Comment: А таймер не подойдёт?

Comment: таймер для этого не предназначен