# Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на кнопку, принадлежащую панели, панель не сворачивалась? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на видимую часть `Panel` она увеличивалась в ширине и отображала кнопки, находящиеся на ней. При убирании мыши `Panel` обратно сворачивается. Я сделал увеличение через событие `MouseEnter` и уменьшение через `MouseLeave`, но при наведении на кнопку добавленную в список `Controls` этой `Panel`, панель сворачивается. Вот код

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                yt_Button theory_btn = new yt_Button();
                theory_btn.Name = files[i];
                theory_btn.BackColor = Color.Purple;
                theory_btn.Text = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
                theory_btn.Width = 320;
                theory_btn.Location = new Point(50, 50 + i * 50);
                forButtonPanel.Controls.Add(theory_btn);
                theory_btn.Click += theory_btn_Click;
                theory_btn.MouseEnter += forButtonPanel_MouseEnter;
            }
```

и события

```
 private void forButtonPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int wantWidth = 420;

            while (forButtonPanel.Width != wantWidth)
            {
                forButtonPanel.Width++;
            }
        }
```

```
 private void forButtonPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int wantWidth = 32;

            while (forButtonPanel.Width != wantWidth)
            {
                forButtonPanel.Width--;
            }
        }
```

`while` для того, чтобы `Panel` раскрывалась плавнее

Comment: а что за язык-то? C# Java c++?

Comment: Забыл указать, C#

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265190/373567